# Liferay 7 remote service access denied

Tags: web-services, liferay-7

liferay 7

I have a remote service for one of my service builder entity and I would like to create a method accessible without any authentication (no p_auth parameter or authentication header).

I added the @AccessControlled(guestAccessEnabled = true) to my method but it does not seem to work as it should. When I click "Execute" button I got an exception :

```
    "Access denied to package.classname#methodName"
```

Is it a known bug?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try to navigate to your Liferay Portal’s Control Panel and click on **Service Access Policy** under the **Configuration** heading. Here, you can see the default service access policies and you can add new ones.
This step helped me in solving a very similar case where I faced the "Access denied" error.

For more information please visit:

[https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017896072-Service-Access-Policies]

I hope you will find all this useful,

Best Regards,
Peter

Comment: Thanks Peter. It seems the link you posted is not available anymore; I believe it changed to this other one: [Service Access Policies](https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017896072-Service-Access-Policies)

Comment: Yes indeed, that is the correct link now - thank you :)

Comment: The link is unavailable.

Comment: Hi @iNardex, now I have corrected the link in my answer as well.
https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017896072-Service-Access-Policies